# Searching a column with a checkbox clears the text field

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table with two columns I want to filter. One input is a checkbox and filters column(0) the other input is the default input text field and filters column(4).

The problem I have when using the checkbox is that the input field is cleared. The input filter on the back end isn't affected (Both the checkbox value and original input value are filtered) but the text is deleted.

I created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/y8t9xmuu/

I put a the code below as well. Try searching for "office" or "field" then use the checkbox. You'll see the text in the text input field goes away but doesn't change the filter.

```js
$(function() {

  var oTable = $('#tTable').dataTable({
    "autoWidth": false,
    "order": [],
    "lengthChange": false,
    "paginate": false,
    //Initial Column search
    "searchCols": [{"search": "ABC"}, null, null, null, null, null], 
    "columnDefs": [{
        "orderable": false,
        "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
      }, //Diasble sorting on certain columns
    ]
  });


  //Default Search
  $('.dataTables_filter input')
    .off()
    .on('keyup input', function(e) {
      oTable.api().column(4).search(this.value, false, true).draw();
    });

  //Checkboxes
  $('.options input:checkbox').change(function() {

    if (this.checked)
      oTable.api().column(0).search('ABC|XYZ', true, false).draw();
    else
      oTable.api().column(0).search('ABC', true, false).draw();

  });
});
```

```css
.tTableWrap {
  display: inline-block;
  width:500px;
  font-size:11px;
}
.tHeader {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
.options {
  height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="tTableWrap">
  <div class="tHeader">Header</div>
  <div class="tMain">
    <div class="options">
      <div class="input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="sListCheck" class="listCheck" />
        <label for="sListCheck" unselectable="on">Include XYZ</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table id="tTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>TYPE</th>
          <th>NAME</th>
          <th>NUMBER</th>
          <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
          <th>ASSIGNED</th>
          <th>DATE</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>ABC</td>
          <td>Joe</td>
          <td>123-456</td>
          <td>Clerk</td>
          <td>Office</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ABC</td>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>123-457</td>
          <td>Assistant</td>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XYZ</td>
          <td>Jane</td>
          <td>123-458</td>
          <td>Clerk</td>
          <td>Field</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XYZ</td>
          <td>Anne</td>
          <td>123-459</td>
          <td>Assistant</td>
          <td>Office</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding behavior of DataTables search box and probably miss something that DataTables does behind the scenes to preserve the value. Also your overridden implementation uses default values for `search()` and could be safely removed. Once removed, the code works fine.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8t9xmuu/27/) for demonstration.

To disable searching for certain columns, use `'searchable': false` in column definitions as shown below.

```
   var oTable = $('#tTable').dataTable({
        "autoWidth": false,
        "aaSorting": [],
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "searchCols": [{ "search": "ABC" }, null, null, null, null, null], //Initial Column search
        "columnDefs": [
           // Diasble sorting on certain columns     
           { "sortable": false, "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] }, 
           // Diasble searching on certain columns     
           { "searchable": false, "targets": [1, 2, 3, 5] }
        ]
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8t9xmuu/28/) for demonstration.

Comment: In my actual application I override the default search to process a number of keywords and modify the search results accordingly. I also need the text input to search only a specific column.

Comment: @SharpBarb, it works without resetting events on `$('.dataTables_filter input')`, see the JSFiddle in my answer.

Comment: I need to override the default search mechanism so I can manipulate the input. (e.g. if (input == "AB") search("^AB$", true,false);

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by disabling the default input field using "dom" and using my own input field. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/f95jg24c/

```
var oTable = $('#tTable').dataTable({
"dom": 'lrtip', //Remove the global filter (Default is 'lfrtip')

....

$('.customSearch input') //Change
    .off()
    .on('keyup input', function (e) {
       oTable.api().column(4).search(this.value, false, true).draw();
    });

<div class="customSearch">
  <label for="Search">Search: </label>
  <input id="Search"/>
</div>
```